# Are Snaplets advisable for larger apps or can you just build directly on top of snap-core?

Tags: haskell, haskell-snap-framework

I plan on writing webapps with Snap.

But sticking with snap-core is much more straightforward to me than using snaplets and lenses.

Is it maintainable in the long-run to start developing with `snap init barebones` and then adding heist templates, HDBC database persistence, etc by hand, without resorting to the Lens stuff? How strongly is the Snap core team encouraging the use of Snaplets in addition to snap-core in practice?

Answer (score 2):

As ocharles said, you can certainly build large web apps in snap-core without using snaplets.  However, snaplets were developed directly from our experience with real world apps.  We observed that we ended up writing a lot of the same boilerplate all the time.  For almost any sufficiently complicated application we found that you'll usually want at least a reader and/or state monad.  In fact, there's a good chance you'll start wanting that even if you only use snap-core + heist because you'll have to pass HeistState around everywhere you use it.

So I would say that the choice between snap and snap-core is roughly equivalent to the choice between C and assembly language.  One might argue that C has these complicated concepts like "for" and "while", but assembly language is much more straightforward with just the simple concept of jmp.  But in the end we all know that C seems to have been worth the cognitive overhead because "for" and "while" embody patterns that we use all the time.

However, I will say that there's a good chance you can build a large web app without needing to write your own snaplet.  There are a number of useful snaplets out there right now that take care of many common tasks and you can use any of them without actually writing your own standalone snaplet.  The only really benefit to writing your own snaplet is if you will use it in more than one web app or if you want to publish it so others can benefit.

Answer (score 1):

It is of course *possible* but I wouldn't recommend it. Snaplets give you a lot of plumbing, essentially for free - and they don't take much work to get going. If you are going to hand-roll HDBC support and stuff, then presumably you'll want to have your own monad, and an instance of `MonadSnap`. I'd wager that already this is more complexity than just using snaplets in the first place.

I don't think sticking with `snap-core` is at all more simple, I'd argue that you're going to produce *more* confusing code, as you now have to write stuff that is not essential to your application.

[Here](https://github.com/metabrainz/musicbrainz-data-service/blob/master/src/MusicBrainz/Service.hs#L85) is a very simple example of me setting up a basic snaplet for a project at work - barely 40 lines of code. Everything you know about snap-core still applies to snaplets (as handlers are instances of `MonadSnap`).

So no - you don't have to use snaplets, but I would personally strongly recommend them.

Comment: Thank you. I'm going to study the Snaplet API with pen and paper this afternoon because of your advice.